# Bootstrap 3.0: nav-tabs not switching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm using bootstrap 3 nav-tabs like this

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right projects"  role="tablist" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <li class="active"><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#progress">In Progress</a></li>
    <li><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#done">Done</a></li>                        
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
 <div id="progress" class="tab-pane fade active in">
     content for progress 
 </div>
 <div id="done" class="tab-pane fade">
   content for done 
 </div>
</div>
```

these are js files i've

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

when page loads tabs are working fine but when i click  second tab and want to come back to first one that does not switch  , whats wrong with my code here pleas help

Comment: Make a jsfiddle or codepen with a demo and come back... this may make more sense...

Answer (score 0):

switch the JavaScript files
Jquery to come first and then bootstrap

Comment: that's same  its changed while i was posting was code

Comment: share your code please, this works fine on my webserver